# Showing lockscreen widget to control application only when the application needs it

Tags: android, android-widget, google-cast, chromecast

I would like to add lockscreen controls for my app similar to what netflix or youtube does when casting to a chromecast device.

Do I do this with a lockscreen widget that I add and remove on demand or is there a different method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to add a lock screen controller is to use the [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html). There are limitations to what you can do there, both in terms of the functionality and availability based on the Android version. If you are running Android version 4.1+, then the required functionality is there (check out the Google Play Music to see how it can look like). Give that a try and if run into issues, come back here and post your issue(s).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have noticed Netflix will sometimes show full screen controls and sometimes above the unlock wheels. Is that all done with the RemoteControlClient?

Comment: RemoteControlClient implementation has changed between JB and KitKat: in JB, it is a small area and in KitKat it is a full screen background image. Netflix, on the other hand, uses a different mechanism which I would call a "hack"; we encourage folks to stay away from any hacks and just rely on the RCC for lock screen implementations.

Comment: @AliNaddaf How do we show the lockscreen image using the new MediaSessionCompat class? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752191/chromecast-sender-v2-7-0-lockscreen-image