# Chromecast Sender v2.7.0 lockscreen image

Tags: java, android, chromecast, google-cast

How do we go about showing the lockscreen artwork for a `chromecast sender` app running `v2.7.0`. I have spent the best part of about 2 days on this without any resolution.

The `v2.7.0` library currently has the following method in the `VideoCastManager.java` class:

```
private void setBitmapForLockScreen(MediaInfo video) {
    if (video == null || mMediaSessionCompat == null) {
        return;
    }
    Uri imgUrl = null;
    Bitmap bm = null;
    List<WebImage> images = video.getMetadata().getImages();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        if (images.size() > 1) {
            imgUrl = images.get(1).getUrl();
        } else if (images.size() == 1) {
            imgUrl = images.get(0).getUrl();
        } else if (mContext != null) {
            // we don't have a url for image so get a placeholder image from resources
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.album_art_placeholder_large);
        }
    } else if (!images.isEmpty()) {
        imgUrl = images.get(0).getUrl();
    } else {
        // we don't have a url for image so get a placeholder image from resources
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
                R.drawable.album_art_placeholder);
    }
    if (bm != null) {
        MediaMetadataCompat currentMetadata = mMediaSessionCompat.getController().getMetadata();
        MediaMetadataCompat.Builder newBuilder = currentMetadata == null
                ? new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                : new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder(currentMetadata);
        mMediaSessionCompat.setMetadata(newBuilder
                .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ART, bm)
                .build());
    } else {
        if (mLockScreenFetchTask != null) {
            mLockScreenFetchTask.cancel(true);
        }
        mLockScreenFetchTask = new FetchBitmapTask() {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (mMediaSessionCompat != null) {
                    MediaMetadataCompat currentMetadata = mMediaSessionCompat.getController()
                            .getMetadata();
                    MediaMetadataCompat.Builder newBuilder = currentMetadata == null
                            ? new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                            : new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder(currentMetadata);
                    mMediaSessionCompat.setMetadata(newBuilder
                            .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ART, bitmap)
                            .build());
                }
                mLockScreenFetchTask = null;
            }
        };
        mLockScreenFetchTask.execute(imgUrl);
    }
}
```

I have tried swaping the `album_art_placeholder_large` drawable with my own custom image, no results. Also tried adding a bitmap via the following line:

```
putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, bm)
```

but nothing works. What exactly am i missing here? What `MediaMetadataCompat` key needs to be used to show the lockscreen artwork??
Or i am looking at the wrong place to begin with?

Some other links i have tried but to no avail:

[Android MediaMetadata image on lockscreen is zoomed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543418/android-mediametadata-image-on-lockscreen-is-zoomed)

[Adding more fields in MediaMetada GoogleCast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600416/adding-more-fields-in-mediametada-googlecast)

The document online as of now is incredibly poor and does not help much.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: On further investigation, it seems to be taking 15-20 minutes after locking the device to show the lockscreen image. Not sure why.

**EDIT 2**: setupMediaSession method.

```
private void setUpMediaSession(final MediaInfo info) {
        if (!isFeatureEnabled(CastConfiguration.FEATURE_LOCKSCREEN)) {
            return;
        }
        if (mMediaSessionCompat == null) {
            ComponentName mediaEventReceiver = new ComponentName(mContext,
                    VideoIntentReceiver.class.getName());
            mMediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(mContext, "TAG", mediaEventReceiver,
                    null);
            mMediaSessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS
                    | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
            mMediaSessionCompat.setActive(true);
            mMediaSessionCompat.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
                    KeyEvent keyEvent = mediaButtonIntent
                            .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                    if (keyEvent != null && (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE
                            || keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY)) {
                        toggle();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPlay() {
                    toggle();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPause() {
                    toggle();
                }

                private void toggle() {
                    try {
                        togglePlayback();
                    } catch (CastException | TransientNetworkDisconnectionException |
                        NoConnectionException e) {
                        LOGE(TAG, "MediaSessionCompat.Callback(): Failed to toggle playback", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);

        PendingIntent pi = getCastControllerPendingIntent();
        if (pi != null) {
            mMediaSessionCompat.setSessionActivity(pi);
        }
        if (info == null) {
            mMediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_NONE, 0, 1.0f).build());
        } else {
            mMediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1.0f)
                .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE).build());
        }

        // Update the media session's image
        updateLockScreenImage(info);

        // update the media session's metadata
        updateMediaSessionMetadata();

        mMediaRouter.setMediaSessionCompat(mMediaSessionCompat);
    }
```

Comment: Where do you call `mMediaSessionCompat.setActive(true)`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake within the setupMediaSession method. I am using the default 2.7.0 library as-is. I have updated the question with the aforementioned method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a "larger" album arts when you defined your MediaInfo? CCL assumes you have a smaller one, set as index=0, which will be used in notification and mini-controller and media router controller dialog and a larger one (second image in MediaInfo, index=1) that will be used for the lockscreen and the fullscreen remote controller. If these images are there, CCL automatically uses them. As a test, run CastVideos-android (v2) and see if that works for you.

Comment: are we talking about the getMetaData().getImages() call within the setBitmapForLockScreen method? I was debugging that method and apparently the list of web images is coming back as 0. However, the extended controls, notification, mini controller all show the correct images

Comment: To add, even if the images is null, looking at the logic implementation it should still pickup the default album_art_placeholder_large and show that if nothing else is available, shouldn't it?

Comment: As I suggested, please try CastVideos-v2 and see if that exhibits this issue or not.